# XSLT - grouping and lost parent's text

Tags: xml, grouping, xslt-2.0

I'm facing a problem where as I try to group code lines into blocks, the text of my parent is lost, and I do not know why.

## XML

```
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>before
      <filepath>one test</filepath> now some code:
      <codeblock>1</codeblock>
      <codeblock>2</codeblock>
      after text</li>
  </ul>
  <section>
    <title>Test2</title>
    <p>qqqq</p>
    <codeblock>1</codeblock>
    <codeblock>2</codeblock>
    <codeblock>3</codeblock>
  </section>
</body>
```

## XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="./codeblock[1] or ./msgblock[1]">
            <xsl:call-template name="merge-codeblock">
                <xsl:with-param name="container" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="merge-codeblock">
    <xsl:param name="container"/>    
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::codeblock or self::msgblock)">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and count(current-group()) gt 1">
                            <xsl:element name="{name()}">
                                <xsl:variable name="name" select="current-group()/node()" />
                                <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/node()">
                                    <xsl:variable name="namee" select="current()" />
                                    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()" />
                                    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
                                </xsl:for-each>
                            </xsl:element>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each-group>
            </xsl:copy>        
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

## Current result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE task PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Task//EN" "dtd/task.dtd"><!--<!DOCTYPE task PUBLIC "-//OASIS//DTD DITA Task//EN" "dtd/task.dtd">--><body>
   <ul>
      <li><!-- not ok! I lost my li/text() -->
         <filepath>one test</filepath>
         <codeblock>1
2
</codeblock>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <section>
      <title>Test</title>
      <p>fddsfsd</p>
      <codeblock>fdsfds</codeblock>
   </section>
   <section>
      <title>Test2</title>
      <p>qqqq</p>
      <codeblock>1
2
3
</codeblock>
   </section>
</body>
```

I've tried adding `|text()` to my group selector which fixes the issue but then my `codeblock` elements are not merged anymore.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
Martin's answer fixes the LI problem, but I unfortunately now have extra spaces before my codeblock lines and a carriage return after the first codeblock:

```
<codeblock>
      1
      2
      3
</codeblock>
```

Instead of:

```
<codeblock>1
2
3</codeblock>
```

How can I get rid of these, I have tried to remove the spaces in current-group() without success yet.

Suggested edit gives me:

```
  <codeblock>

1


2


3

   </codeblock>
```

But the issue remains of the strange white space. current-group() contains `"      ", <codeblock>, "      ", <codeblock>, "      ", <codeblock>, "   "`with carriage returns in the blank spaces.

Comment: Which output do you want? And can there be any elements inside the codeblock elements or only plain text? I guess in the latter case the easiest approach is to use `<xsl:value-of select="current-group()" separator="&#10;"/>` instead of `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>`.

Comment: I have tried your idea but it still fails, I have posted some details in case you have another idea :).

Comment: See the edit of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[codeblock | msgblock]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each-group select="node()"
                group-adjacent="boolean(self::text()[not(normalize-space())] | self::codeblock | self::msgblock)">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[self::*]">
                        <xsl:element name="{name(current-group()[self::*[1]][1])}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:for-each-group>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="codeblock | msgblock">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

groups and keeps the text, you might need to adapt the part outputting the grouped content as I am not sure which exact result you want.

As for your problems with white space, assuming you simply have plain text in those `codeblock` and `msgblock` elements then you can simplify

```
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[self::*]">
                        <xsl:element name="{name(current-group()[self::*[1]][1])}">
                            <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
```

to

```
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and current-group()[self::*]">
                        <xsl:element name="{name(current-group()[self::*[1]][1])}">
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[self::*]" separator="&#10;"/>
                        </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:when>
```

Comment: Once again, very good approach. It seems it's working great according to my first tests. Thank you very much!

Comment: I have updated  the question to show an issue that i have noticed and that I've been trying to fix without much success for now. Any help would be appreciated.